# Run Edge browser as a different user

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to run the new Edge browser as a different user?  I found an article showing how to run as the built-in Administrator account, but I need to run it as a different AD user, not a built-in account.  With IE11 (and Chrome, for that matter) this can be done by shift-clicking.  Shift-clicking Edge just brings up one item: "open".

Can this be done?

Comment: Supply us the information you read.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make a shortcut to:

`%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge`

2. Then you can run it as a different user by going to Application Tools -> Manage then clicking the dropdown and selecting "Run as another user".
3. (Optional) If <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Clicking and selecting "Run as another user" works for you then you can do that instead.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you'll need to do is go to `C:\Windows\SystemApps` and look for the folder that starts with `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge`. Then go to the file `MicrosoftEdge.exe` <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd>. There you will see **Run as different user**.

**Update:**

Since Edge is a windows app you need to run it like this `explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge`. So what you can do is put this in a shortcut then you will have the ability to do the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Click</kbd>.

Comment: Only this doesn't work. Opening MicrosoftEdge.exe doesn't work. (For myself and quite a few others at least)

Comment: @Insane I just realized that as well and updated my answer.

Comment: You can't Shift + Right Click and select run as different user on it, at least for me when I tried. However upon testing it seems some shortcuts you can. Unsure why that is.

Comment: @Insane Yes you can actually, at least I can. http://i.imgur.com/8jEX0eC.png

Comment: No idea why I don't have it :P

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for the domain user I need it to work for.  It does give a better option for run-as administrator than the one I found previously, though.  Not sure what kind of permissions are required to run Edge, but I added the user I was trying to local administrators, and still no dice.

Comment: Dave could I suggest a better browser that can actually support what you want out of the box (i.e. Chrome, Firefox)? Also @imtheman that's possible.

Comment: @Insane I primarily use Chrome, but find that certain Microsoft products (SharePoint, TFS Web, etc.) often work better when using a Microsoft browser.  i could still use IE11 as it is installed, but would rather not.  As it stands, I will probably need to use Chrome for these instances.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Yeah don't get me wrong I actually use Edge for quick surfing-- it's not a bad browser-- but you can't beat Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Just run into the same problem. 
You need to open Edge in a private window. When you enter an URL or use a favorite, you should be prompt for credentials!

**[Edit]**
**[Browse InPrivate in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026200/microsoft-edge-browse-inprivate)**

> In Microsoft Edge, select the Settings and More (...) icon, and then New
>   InPrivate window. Microsoft Edge InPrivate browsing
>   [image]

Comment: Great suggestion, now if only you could tell us how to open Edge in a private window!

Comment: @RandyGamage: edit for steps ;)

Comment: thanks!  Unfortunately that option does not appear for me, my corporate overlords have removed this option.  :-(

Comment: This isn't going to change the credentials under which the program is run, though it will let you log into sites with a different account since it won't use your standard browser cache to retrieve any cached login credentials.

Comment: This method worked for me in Windows Admin Center.