# Opening Microsoft Edge in Elevated mode (use case: open via Selenium)

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge, privileges, selenium

I am trying to open Ms Edge in Elevated Mode, but I am unable to do so. (Windows 11)

I have tried to open it manually too, but the Elevated option is always set to 'No'

I have tried using the below options via selenium

```
    admin_edge_options = webdriver.IeOptions()    
    admin_edge_options.use_chromium = True
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--ie-mode-test')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    admin_edge_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    driver = webdriver.Ie(options=admin_edge_options)
```

Manually I have tried

1. Run as Administrator:

- Right-click on the Microsoft Edge shortcut or executable.
- Choose "Run as administrator" to launch Edge with elevated privileges.

2. Run after Temporarily disabling windows defender

I tried to perform the same on another Machine (windows 10),facing the same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Edge browser as a different user](https://superuser.com/questions/998690/run-edge-browser-as-a-different-user)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik does that apply to Edge Chromium? 2015 was still old Edge, I believe.

Comment: It doesnt @DrMoishePippik , I was able to figure it out with playing around with settings -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78131995/opening-microsoft-edge-in-elevated-mode-use-case-open-via-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out with by messing around settings.

1. Open Edge file location.
2. Open properties -> compatibility. Click change settings for all users
3. Check 'Run this program as an Administrator'.
4. Apply. Ok

Refer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78131995/opening-microsoft-edge-in-elevated-mode-use-case-open-via-selenium